# Obj-C, showing a UIPickerView in an UIActionSheet, but need to save to NSUserDefaults and refresh table contents, but where?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I was using `pickerView didSelectRow` to save the selected value to NSUserDefaults and re populate my table view. However, at the point the action sheet / picker view is still visible and the user can select new values and didSelectRow will be called again.

EDIT: To clarify I don't want to populate my table view at this point.

I'm looking for an event when I can save the value and re-populate after the picker view is dismissed.

What can I use ?

Here's my code to show the action sheet / picker view.

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
NSString *title = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].
   orientation) ? @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" : @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" ;
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[[[UIActionSheet alloc] init] 
  initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", 
  title, NSLocalizedString(@"Select the recurrence", @"")] delegate:self 
  cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] autorelease];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

UIPickerView *pickerView = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init] autorelease];

pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
}
```

Comment: I did this but I dont get a button in the UIPicker toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dismissing the action sheet using the OK button defined above then you can use the action sheet delegate method  `actionSheet:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` method. If you store the picker's selection in the picker view delegate methods, then write it to defaults when the action sheet is dismissed, this should cover you.

Comment: Store in pickers delegate methods?

Comment: Yes, the same object is the picker view delegate and action sheet delegate, so when the picker view is updated, put the selected value in an ivar, then when the sheet is dismissed, write that ivar to defaults.